# jQuery: Facebook iframe app html inaccessible

Tags: jquery, facebook

Why cant I access the embedded app elements?

Looking at the HTML, the app is put inside a div but when I try to find the div contents, e.g.

```
$("input").get()
```

I only see input element of FB, not the app. I injected jQuery after the page load with FireQuery plugin.

How can the HTML looks fine but cannot be traversed with jQuery?

Comment: security, u cant if the iframe src is on another domain

Comment: But I thought if it's rendered as HTML div then you can access it with javascript as how it is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Your app is an iframe app right?

What happens if you load jquery normally in your html for your iframe?  That should work to access DOM elements in your iframe...it works for my iframe Facebook apps.

I haven't played with FireQuery, but it sounds like it dynamically injects jquery for experimenting/debugging.  I'm guessing you are somehow loading it into the Facebook domain, not your iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the CD command of the Firebug console.
http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API#cd.28window.29

This will change the context of the command line to that of the window which you give as a reference to the cd function.

Something like this would do:
`cd(frames["idOfIFrame"])`

From there, you can do your usual command line stuff like you would on a normal website.

Comment: Also, you should note, the FB IFrame is just that, an IFrame. It's not rendered in a div! It's 'rendered' into the IFrame, by FB POST'ing a form into the IFrame using javascript. This is also how the signed_request details from FB make it into your IFrame app, via the POST.